# Why hdfs namenode and datanode both always listen on 0.0.0.0 at a random port?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I installed a new hadoop-2.2.0 today, I found after hdfs is started (using /sbin/start-dfs.sh), namenode and datanode both always listen on 0.0.0.0 at a random port? I cannot find relate configuration on http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml.

The port is not 50070, 50470, 50090, 50010, 50020, 50075, 50475...etc. which are listed on hdfs-default.xml, it is just a random port.

```
8369 Jps
8109 DataNode
7936 NameNode
```

Namenode listens on the followings:

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:46628 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 7936/java        <==
tcp 0 0 10.173.130.119:9000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 7936/java
tcp 0 0 10.173.130.119:50070 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 7936/java
```

Datanode listens on the followings:

```
tcp 0 0 10.173.130.119:50020 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 8109/java
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:35114 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 8109/java        <==
tcp 0 0 10.173.130.119:50010 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 8109/java
tcp 0 0 10.173.130.119:50075 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 8109/java
```

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Does anyone know how to change this listener of 0.0.0.0:random_port? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes It assigns random port everytime a namenode or datanode restarted. But if you observer all the namenode listeners running on same process id in this case (7936) and Datanode listeners run on same process id ie 8109. So internally process is same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to find some way to configure or change this behavior, because no one is allowed to bind on 0.0.0.0 in my company.